# XTerm js not handling special characters like \n "\u001b[H\u001b[2J\u001b[3J" in term.write

Tags: terminal, utf-8, xtermjs

I am using Xterm Js to create a console in my web browser, so far I have successfully implemented the functionality on server side but having a problem when it comes to represent the output

1. When I type in `clear` command in my XTerm it returns `\u001b[H\u001b[2J\u001b[3J` which I believe is a correct output from my back-end, however when I write this output using `term.write` it posts the entire string instead of clearing the screen
2. Same goes for my `ls` command it returns `<file_name_1>\n<file_name_2>\n<file_name_3>\n` It prints all the `\n` instead of going to a new line.

How do I make XTerm Js NOT to 'sanitize' the output and make those special characters perform their respective task like \n for new line, etc without simply posting the string.

Comment: When you see that output from `clear` literally been written to the terminal, then at some stage of your input processing the original data got rewritten into escaped data, e.g. '\n' --> '\\n'. Check your processing steps for those double backslashes. In 2. you have another problem - `ls` should not output 'file1\nfile2...' if properly run behind a pty, but 'file1\r\nfile2...'. Imho you miss the pty layer between.

Comment: Thanks for the reply actually the problem was similar to what you mentioned. It was having double backslashes.